# Renombrar un archivo en python

Tags: python

Hola tengo este código en python

```
import os
path = "/home/dev06/Descargas/prueba nombre/id/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
i="4"
for fn in dirs:
    src = path + fn
    dst = path + fn[-8:-7] str(i) 
    print(dst)
    if fn[-8] == "6":
        os.rename(src, dst)
        print("objeto encontrado")
```

La funcionalidad del script es la de remplazar el 6 por una variable que en este caso es un 4. El problema esta que en vez de remplazar el 6 el agrega despues del 6 un 4. Como puedo hacer que funcione?

Comment: Hola alberto, en la linea `dst = path + fn[-8:-7] str(i)`  te falta algo entre `fn[-8:-7]` y `str(i)`, tal como lo tienes es un error de sintaxis...

Comment: Por otro lado, quieres modificar el nombre de archivos, de ficheros o de ambos (porque listdir no discrimina). Por otro lado, ¿los nombres de tus archivos/ficheros siguen algún patrón en concreto? ¿Que pasa si el número a reemplazar tiene más de 1 cifra?

Comment: Si el carácter a substituir está en posición -8 deberías hacer en todo caso  `fn[:-8]  + str(i) + fn[-8:]`. Ten claro cual es el elemento -8, en `"abcdefghi"` es `"b", pudiera que estuvieras indizando el elemento incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

He logrado la solución a este problema, el resultado fue este

```
import os
path = "/home/dev06/Descargas/prueba nombre/id/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
i="4"
for fn in dirs:
    src = path + fn
    dst = path + fn[:-8] + str(i) + fn[-7:] 
    print(dst)

    if fn[-8] == "6":
       os.rename(src, dst)
        #print("objeto encontrado")
```

los cambios que hice fue en esta linea:
dst = path + fn[:-8] + str(i) + fn[-7:]
fn[-8] es la  posicion de la letra que se remplazara por Str(i)
luego despues del remplazo le agrego las letras siguientes(fn[-7:]) para completar el nombre.
gracias FJSevilla por tus comentarios

Comment: Considera explicar tu código, de modo que la comunidad sepa que modificaste o agregaste y el aporte les sea de utilidad a todos los que consulten